# Check if key exist in array if so, count it and create a new array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

From my SQL query, I will get the following array as a result. This is the last result I can get from SQL.I cant change any SQL because of some constraint.
I need to check if the same id exists or not and if it does need to count them and remove one of the duplicate array having the same id. 
Sample array is

```
$array = array(
          0 => array(
            'id' => '17',
            'status' => 1,


          ),
          1 => array(
            'id' => '18',
            'status' => 1,


          ),
          2 => array(
            'id' => '21',
            'status' => 1,


          ),
          3 => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'status' => 2,


          ),
          4 => array(
            'id' => '18',
            'status' => 1,


          ),
          5 => array(
            'id' => '22',
            'status' => 5,


          ),
          6 => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'status' => 1,


          ),
        );
```

I need to check if they have a duplicate id or not, if yes need to count them and remove one of the duplicates.We need to preserve the array structure.

End Results should be

```
array(
  0 => array(
    'id' => '17',
    'status' => 1,
'count'=1,

  ),
  1 => array(
    'id' => '18',
    'status' => 1,
'count'=2,



  ),
  2 => array(
    'id' => '21',
    'status' => 1,
'count'=1,


  ),
  3 => array(
    'id' => '5',
    'status' => 2,
'count'=1,


  ),
  4 => array(
    'id' => '22',
    'status' => 5,
'count'=1,


  ),

  5 => array(
    'id' => '6',
    'status' => 1,
'count'==>1,
  ),
)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? show your current code

Comment: Let me know if you need any help with my answer.

Comment: duplicate is on array index 1 and 4 with id =18

Comment: $test=array();
$counts = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$subarr) {

  if (array_key_exists($subarr['id'],$test)) {
      $test=$subarr;
      $test['count']=$test[$subarr['id']]++;
     
  }
  
    else{  
        $test=$subarr;
      $test['count']=1;
    }
    array_push($counts,$test);

}
This is what I have tried so far. I am missing small things I guess.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question to add any attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Check it by this way but duplicate entry still in the array.

```
$ids = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
{
   $ids[] = $value['id'];
   $count = array_count_values($ids);
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($array);$i++)
{

  $array[$i]['count'] = $count[$array[$i]['id']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `array_unique` function.

Use it like so:

```
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"red");
print_r(array_unique($a));
```

Which outputs:

```
Array ( [a] => red [b] => green )
```

Comment: How would this give the OP the expected output? (Note the `count`-parameter in the expected output)